# android use pagging library how remove particular item

Tags: android

My android app show list of user.I use paging library but dynamically add remove user from that list.

so i remove particular item from the list.its show me livedata is immutable 
cannot edit that.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing from the actual response list and update the MutableLiveData with the list.

```
//This is your actual response list
responseList.remove(position)

//Well this is your liveData
liveData.value = responseList
```

Comment: i need to update that particular position only.
so i use room db found in google android developer website.